# Parallelizing a for loop that uses BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: multithreading, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing, html-parsing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to optimize the following loop:

```
all_a = []

for i in range(0, len(final_all)):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(final_all[i], 'html.parser')
    for t in soup.select('table[width="100%"]'):
        t.extract()
        for row in soup.select('tr'):
            name = row.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ').split('—', maxsplit=1)
            if name not in all_a:
                all_a.append(name)
```

where `final_all` is a list of 30,000 html documents that look like the `.html` from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679183/storing-information-from-td-tags-with-a-specific-width-in-python).

The time to parse one html document is less than one second.

I was thinking if there is a smart way to combine both loops that use `soup.select()` in one loop. I also unsuccessfully tried using sets.

I also tried `multiprocessing` with only 30 observations, but I am clearly making a mistake:

```
%%time
all_a = [] 

    def worker(data):
        for i in range(0, len(data)):
            start = time.time()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(data[i], 'html.parser')
            for t in soup.select('table[width="100%"]'):
                t.extract()
                for row in soup.select('tr'):
                    name = row.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ').split('—', maxsplit=1)
                    if name not in all_a:
                        all_a.append(name)

test = final_all[0:30]

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    pool = mp.Pool(8) # os.cpu_count*2  
    start = time.time()
    final = worker(test)


CPU times: user 1min 50s, sys: 2.91 s, total: 1min 53s
Wall time: 1min 48s
```

Compared to the times when I do not use multiprocessing:

```
CPU times: user 1min 39s, sys: 1.78 s, total: 1min 41s
Wall time: 1min 39s
```

Comment: This sounds like a good job for [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
all_a = []
for i in range(0, len(final_all)):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(final_all[i], 'html.parser')
    for t in soup.select('table[width="100%"]'):
        t.extract()
    for row in soup.select('tr'): # Out of the loop above
        name = row.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ').split('—', maxsplit=1)
        all_a.append(name)
all_a = list(set(all_a))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not return all the observations.

Comment: @Antarqui If the amount of data is large, it is recommended that you store it in the database to do the duplication.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is not related to storage. The third loop needs to be nested in the second one.